# How to override authenticated user permissions?

Tags: 7, users

I'm looking after an intranet site on D7. 
Our system daily gets a user feed from active directory and puts everyone (new/existing users) as authenticated User. Authenticated users have the permission to comment on nodes. Is there any way I can create a role which override authenticated role permissions so if I want to ban a user of writing comments/creating nodes etc...

Comment: I suggest doing it the other way around - have a "whitelisted" role whose members can post comments, while regular authenticated users cannot. Authenticated user role is created so you can have common permissions for all members of the site.

Comment: @Topsitemakers, thanks for your quick response but what I'm looking here is a way to override existing authenticated user permissions.